# Preserving data In the Backstack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, back-button

I have an application that fetches a list of option from a server based of a unique id (uid). When you click on option it provides another list based on a uid as it did in the first activity. It passes the uid of the option clicked to the next activity so  it can fetch the data. When you press back, the activity before forgets its uid, and throws a null pointer exception cause it tries to fetch with a null uid. How can i get the previous activity to preserve data as it sits in the backstack or how can I pass data from activity 2 to activity 1 on the back press so I can give it its uid?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `addToBackStack`?  Some code surrounding your fragment transaction management might help.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, please add your code and logcat to your post. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you start the second activity the first one is destroyed. When you go back, the first activity is initialized, but this is a new instance.

You could use startActivityForResult() when you start the second activity. And let the second activity pass back the UID to the first activity when it is finished.

Or you could save the Uid in shared preferences, the application object or a Static class/ singleton.

Comment: Your first activity will only be destroyed if user call finish method, also if activity destroyed you cannot go back to it. application will be closed.

Comment: If this is true, just put it in a local variable and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article on google developer about saving activity state : 
[here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)